# Find specific characters and return the next value in the cell using Excel Formula

Tags: excel, return, contains

I am not sure where to begin with the formula as I have gotten myself so confused with everything.  I have a cell the contains "PON " or "PON: " or "PON = " then the actual PON (Example: PON 123467) I want to formula to return 123467 in the cell.

```
Examples                                         What I want returned
I have PON 123467 for shoes                         123467
I have PON: 234567-AB for food                      234567-AB
I have PON - 569874-Weird for accessories           569874-Weird
I have PON = DOG-564-987 for dog food               DOG-564-987
```

I am currently using Excel 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `FILTERXML`, and testing for a substring following `PON`, you can try:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'PON')]/following-sibling::*[string-length(.)>2][1]")
```

*Note that FILTERXML solution will cause a PON that is solely numeric, but with a leading zero, to drop the leading zero. Unfortunately, the xPath implementation in that function does not include the `string()` function*

*If dropping the leading zero might be a problem, you can add a character to the node that will force the number to be seen as a string. In the modified formula below, I use the unicode zero-width space, but there are others you can use. Note that this will count as a character for the `string=length` function, so be sure to maintain the `>2` parameter*:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ","</s><s>"&UNICHAR(8203)) & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'PON')]/following-sibling::*[string-length(.)>2][1]")
```

Because of the variablity in your data, that sometimes there are extraneous space-separated substrings between PON and your desired extract, the xpath:

- locates the substring `PON`
- returns all subsequent siblings that have a string-length of more than two (*adjust if necessary*)

  - returns the first sibling that meets that criterion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Filterxml()` will give you best companion here in this case. Try-

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," for","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[1]")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

[image]

Comment: If I am following your logic, I think you could eliminate the `SUBSTITUTE` and execute it all with the xPath: `//s[contains(.,'for')]/preceding-sibling::*[1]`

Comment: I do not research much more on it. I will try it. May be your way will better but who has no knowledge about 'xPath' function, it will hard for to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this formula.

```
=TRIM(LEFT(MID(A2,FIND(@{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2),100),FIND(" ",MID(A2,FIND(@{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2),100))))
```

It extracts the text between the first number and the first space following that number. The size of that extract is limited to 100 characters.